# how can i change Admin custom menu icon in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have a png image and I want to replace the default icon of the custom menu in the admin panel in Magento. I tried to other articles who are customizing their code in the app/code/Vendor/Module/ folder but that was not working for me so please suggest any simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to this way ..

You need to create `adminhtml.css` file to set our custom style and link for icon and replace **icon.png** link with your icon URL.

we have to link our CSS file by creating **default.xml** file at following path.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Extension::css/adminhtml.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\web\css\adminhtml.css

```
.admin__menu .level-0.item-menu_id > a:before {
    content: url('../images/icon.png');
}
li#menu-vendor_extension-menu_id > a > span {
    display: none;
}
```

then run some commands

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Hi  @Rakesh any idea on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/323170/restrict-product-from-adding-to-cart-based-on-product-type

Answer (score 1):

We have 2 ways to customize the menu logo in admin.

1. Custom by css

- Create file admin-icon.css in module app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\adminhtml\web\css
- Add image logo in module. Ex: custom-logo.png
- Create an xml file in the module and declare the newly created css file in that xml file.

[image]

- Contents in the css file.

[image]

- ".item-menu_id" is the outer class of the icon.
- Run command

  rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
  rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy